# How to make Apache so that it does not use the .htaccess file

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

How can I make Apache so that it doesn't check for .htaccess files at all. Because, it is said that it reduces performance. Does it reduce performance if there is no .htaccess file in the directory and its directories? If so, how can I disable Apache from checking for .htaccess file at all? I have already set `AllowOverride None`, but it still checks for .htaccess files and processes them.

Comment: On Apache 2.4, `.htaccess` overrides are disabled by default, so if this is enabled on your server then it must have already been explicitly enabled _somewhere_ in the server config. Assuming you have full access to the server then you need to find where this is being enabled, before trying to disable (or override) it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered in the [When (not) to use `.htaccess` files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when) section of Apache HTTP Server Tutorial for `.htaccess` files:

> There are two main reasons to avoid the use of .htaccess files.
>
> The first of these is performance. When [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) is set to allow
>   the use of `.htaccess` files, httpd will look in every directory for
>   `.htaccess` files. Thus, permitting `.htaccess` files causes a performance
>   hit, whether or not you actually even use them! Also, the `.htaccess`
>   file is loaded every time a document is requested.

You **must** use the [`AllowOverride None`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) in the **directory context**:

> `AllowOverride` is valid only in
>   `<Directory>` sections specified without regular expressions, not in
>   `<Location>`, `<DirectoryMatch>` or `<Files>` sections.

To globally disable `.htaccess` files (unless explicitly allowed in another `<Directory>` section):

```
<Directory "/">
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

And do not forget to reload Apache after modifying the configuration.

Comment: It is already set, but htaccess files still work, why? Also, thanks for your previous answer.

Comment: Carefully look through the configuration for other `AllowOverride` directives that may turn the feature back on on inner directory trees.

Comment: Ok, let me just do that.

Comment: Nope, I see no other setting than `AllowOverride None`

Comment: Should I remove the `AccessFileName .htaccess` directive?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that, as the `AllowOverride` controls the usage of the feature.